# Recursively put array of string to json

Tags: java, json, tree, nodes

Trying to put this list of strings into a json format. The list of strings looks like a directory structure.

Would like the final out put to be like

```
[{"name":"Cars","show":false,"nodes":[{"name":"Truck","show":false,"nodes":[{"name":"Regular","show":false,"nodes":[]},{"name":"4x4","show":false,"nodes":[{"name":"Lifted","show":false,"nodes":[]}]}]},{"name":"Jeep","show":false,"nodes":[{"name":"4x4","show":false,"nodes":[]}]},{"name":"Convertable","show":false,"nodes":[]}]}]
```

What i have so far can pick out the final item but i'm not sure how this helps me thus far

```
    String[] li = new String[4];
    li[0] = "Cars/Truck/Regular";
    li[1] = "Cars/Truck/4x4/Lifted";
    li[2] = "Cars/Jeep/4x4";
    li[3] = "Cars/Convertable";
    doAll(li);

    public void doAll(String[] files) {
    try {
        for (String file : files) {
            String[] f = file.split("/");
            if (f.length>1) {
                logger.info("directory:"+file);
                f = (String[]) ArrayUtils.removeElement(f, f[0]);
                String temp = "";
                for(String ff : f) temp=temp+"/"+ff;
                temp = temp.replaceFirst("/", "");
                doAll(new String[]{temp});
            } else if(f.length==1){
                logger.info("file:"+file);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using Jackson. The object mapper in Jackson can help with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an object and generate the json from that object? You can create class for each type of object you have in your json. For example, you could have a class called node:

```
public class node() {

  private String name;
  private boolean show;
  private node[] nodes;

  //getters and setters

}
```

Then, you can set your object with all of your vehicle data and use gson to generate your json.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(node);
```

Comment: yes i understand that part. but where within the doAll would I put the object?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't think you will need the doAll() method if you use gson. You could create a new node object ex) Node node = new Node() and then set the values ex) node.setName("Cars") node.setShow(false) etc....then use gson to generate your json string